# How do I change the leftbarbuttonitem color in ios7.0

Tags: ios7, uinavigationitem

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

I have done above,but it doesn't work.The color is still as same as the background color!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create button and substitute

```
   UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.leftBarButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
```

or

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)itemWithNormalImage:(UIImage*)normalImage
                           pressedImage:(UIImage*)pressedImage
                                 target:(id)target
                                 action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:normalImage
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:pressedImage
            forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setImage:pressedImage
            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalImage.size.width, normalImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem* item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    return item;
}
```

Text color:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
[item setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[item];
```